# How many solutions of $ x+y+z+t = 7 $

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I have an equation: $ x+y+z+t = 7$. I want to know how many solutions does this equation have? $x,y,z$, and $t$ are positive integers. I have no idea how to solve this. Can you please help me to solve this question?

Comment: Are $x,y,z,t$ natural numbers? Integers? Rationals? Reals?

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisets#Counting_multisets

Comment: Positive integers .

Comment: Put $7$ sticks and count how many ways you can choose three of the spaces between them to put the $+$ signs.

Comment: It has infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Ok, I see. I did pay attention to the rest of the question.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: It wasn't added to the original question, but it was mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is classic [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) combinatorics question.

We need to find 4 numbers, i.e. 4-tuples of positive integers such their sum is 7. So the number of solution is:

$$\binom{k-1}{n-1}$$

Where $k$ is their sum and $n$ is the the number of terms in the summation. So for our case we have:

$$\binom{7-1}{4-1} = \binom{6}{3} = 20 \text{ solutions}$$

Note that some of this solution are permutations because $(x,y,z,y) = (1,2,2,2)$ and $(x,y,z,y) = (2,1,2,2)$ are calculated twice. If you want solutions like these to be included just once, I can't think of a better way than counting.

Comment: If you want your solutions to not depend on permutations (i.e. $(x,y,z,t) = (1,2,2,2)$ and $(x,y,z,t) = (2,1,2,2)$ are the same), you need to have a look at *integer partitions*.
Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no (simple) closed form for $p(n,k)$ the number of partitions of $n$ in $k$ parts. However, you have its generating function
$$ \sum_{n,k\geq 1}p(n,k)x^{k}q^{n} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-xq^{n}}$$
To determine the number of your solutions, all you have to do is take the term $[x^{4},q^{7}]$ out of this function
$$[x^{4},q^{7}]\;\prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{1-xq^{n}}$$

Comment: I don't quite understand you. Do we have to expand that product expression and find the coefficient in front of $x^4q^7$ which is the number of distinct integer partitions of 7 into 4 parts.

Comment: Exactly. Although it may look as hard as the original problem (to count the number of partitions of 7 in 4 parts), this can be used to find the solution numerically with Taylor expansion.

Comment: @Stefan4024 So, what to do, if I want to count only unordered cases? For example in your answer 2+2+2+1 and 2+2+1+2 are different, but if it's the same?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a hint to help you get started thinking about the problem. There might be a cleaver way to look at this, but you could also simply just count the number of solutions. So you start
$$
1 + 1 + 1 + 4 = 7 \\
1 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 7 \\
1 + 1 + 3 + 2 = 7 \\
1 + 1 + 4 + 1 = 7 \\
1 + 2 + 1 + 3 = 7 \\
1 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 7 \\
\vdots
$$

Maybe a slightly smarter way to do it would be first to notice that $x,y,z,t$ need to be from $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then figure out how many ways you can add these up to get $7$. You get (Note for example that if one number is $3$, then the other numbers have to be $1$ or $2$):
$$
1, 1, 1, 4 \\
1, 1, 2, 3 \\
1, 2, 2, 2. \\
$$
If you pick $1,1,1,4$ then how many ways can you add these up?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

$x+y+z+t=7$, but since they are all integers we write $x=m+1$,  $y=n+1$, $z=o+1$, and $t =p+1$ (where $m,n,o,p$ are non negative integers). Then $m+n+o+p=3$. There are three options. One of them is $3$ and the others are $0$. One is $2$ and another is $1$ or three are $1$.

The first case gives $4$ solutions, the second $12$ (number ordered pairs of the subset $\{m,n,o,p\}$) and the third $4$. Therefore there are $20$ solutions all in all.